# javascript: using ternary operator for if/else if/else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I was looking at these if statements:

```
 if (cellDate < filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
    return -1;
 } else if (cellDate > filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
    return 1;
 } else {
    return 0;
 }
```

from [this article](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-date/#gsc.tab=0) and I was wondering why short hand if statements were not used (I.e. using the ternary operator)> is there a disadvantage to using it? It seems like a good opportunity to use it.

If it can be used, is the below how you would simplify it? I'd like to refactor my code although I'm a little worried about straying from the example in the article (and inadvertently introducing some special case glitches)

```
cellDate < filterLocalDateAtMidnight ? -1 :(cellDate > filterLocalDateAtMidnight : 1 : 0 );
```

i assume the separate if statements are used in case of null/undefined values?

Comment: Your ternary expression correctly represents the if else statements. If else statements can be expressed in a compact way using ternary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested ternaries are confusing to read and should generally avoided. See the [Airbnb style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#comparison--nested-ternaries).

With numerical comparisons you can usually just use subtraction. i.e.

```
return cellDate - filterLocalDateAtMidnight;
```

But beware that this solution is vulnerable to integer overflow for really large numbers.